# adding html element using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have generated html content

```
<a href="/images/img1.jpg" target="_blank">
   <img src="/images/img1.jpg" alt="asdsadasdsa" />
</a>
```

how can I on dom ready use image alt content (in this case asdsadasdsa) and add new attribute title with alt image content, in other words above html should be

```
<a href="/images/img1.jpg" target="_blank" title="asdsadasdsa">
    <img src="/images/img1.jpg" alt="asdsadasdsa" />
</a>
```

js should target only code which has `target="_blank"` as part of a href attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
var $target = $('a[target="_blank"]');
var $content = $target.find('img').attr('alt');

$target.attr('title', $content);
```

or this way:

```
var $target = $('a[target="_blank"]');

$target.each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle to try**](http://jsfiddle.net/5X6LW/)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$('a[target="_blank"]:has(img[alt])').attr('title', function () {
    return $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
});
```

DEMO - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TkhUV/)

Reference

[**:has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

[**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[**[ ] has-attribute-selector**](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I should target only links which has target="_blank" like <a href="/images/img1.jpg" target="_blank" ...